# Java List , Vector comparison

Tags: java, list, vector, comparison

I saw the following program on the internet

```
public class Test1{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 Integer int1 = new Integer(10);
 Vector vec1 = new Vector();
 LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
 vec1.add(int1);
 list.add(int1);
 if(vec1.equals(list)) System.out.println("equal");
 else  System.out.println("not equal");
  }
```

}

The answer it print is "equal".

How it is possible?

Thanks

Dilip

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/Theequalsmethodisusedtocheckforelementequality.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because both a LinkedList and Vector implement [List#equals()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both
>   lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in
>   the two lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if
>   (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are
>   defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same
>   order. This definition ensures that the equals method works properly
>   across different implementations of the List interface.

Specifically, here is the exact reason for this behavior.

**This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the List interface.**

Answer (score 4):

Here's the API doc for [`Vector.equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) (other `List` implementations behave similarly):

> Compares the specified Object with this Vector for equality. Returns
>   true if and only if the specified Object is also a List, both Lists
>   have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two
>   Lists are equal.

Comment: Thank you so much for your all answers

Answer (score 2):

See the javadoc for equals on java.util.Vector:

```
  /**
     * Compares the specified Object with this Vector for equality.  Returns
     * true if and only if the specified Object is also a List, both Lists
     * have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two
     * Lists are <em>equal</em>.  (Two elements {@code e1} and
     * {@code e2} are <em>equal</em> if {@code (e1==null ? e2==null :
     * e1.equals(e2))}.)  In other words, two Lists are defined to be
     * equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.
     *
     * @param o the Object to be compared for equality with this Vector
     * @return true if the specified Object is equal to this Vector
     */
```

The equals method is checking that the lists have the same contents in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

Definition of `equals` implementation on `Vector`:

> Compares the specified Object with this Vector for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified Object is also a List, both Lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two Lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two Lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.

Both `Vector` and `LinkedList` are descendents of [AbstractList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) (in the case of `LinkedList`, there's an extra class in between I believe). `AbstractList` objects can be compared to one another.

Answer (score 0):

It is because they are both lists.

`Vector` and `LinkedList` both inherit ultimately from `AbstractList`.

See the implementation of `equals` on line 512 of [the source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/AbstractList.java.html).

Answer (score 0):

That's because both LinkedList and Vector internally call the same method [java.util.AbstractList.equals()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to do the comparison.